# forecasting in fable ARIMA blowing up

Tags: r, forecasting, fable-r

I am trying to fit an ARIMA model (fable package) where I include dummies.
Here is the code I am using

```
mod_region <- aggregated_region %>% 
  filter(SETTLEMENTDATE < '2020-02-11') %>% 
  model( 
    arima = ARIMA(sum ~ as.factor(Day))
  )
fc_region <- mod_region %>% 
  forecast(h='7 days’)
```

It gives this error:

> “Error: object 'Day' not found
>   Unable to compute required variables from provided `new_data`.
>   Does your model require extra variables to produce forecasts?”

I tried looking up on google but couldn’t figure out anything.

I earlier thought maybe it’s creating 7 dummies and that’s why the code blows up and then I tested using
    `arima = ARIMA(sum ~ I(Day == ’Sunday’))`
But it gives the same error at the time of using forecast() function.

Do you know why this might be happening?

Comment: Try creating your factor variable before calling the model function.

Comment: @RobHyndman Thanks for that Rob. I tried doing that. It now gives this error `[5] variable lengths differ (found for 'xreg')`

Comment: Please provide a reproducible example.

Comment: @RobHyndman I have uploaded some data into the file here (https://drive.google.com/file/d/1ZI95SnJOTVVtbil84eq7n1F5mei5GeJL/view?usp=sharing) and I am using this code:

Comment: @RobHyndman
`aggregated_region <- readRDS('aggregated_region.rds')

aggregated_region_train <- aggregated_region %>% 
  filter(Date < '2020-02-11')
xreg_region_new_m <- aggregated_region %>% 
  filter(Date >= '2020-02-11')
xreg_region <- as.factor(aggregated_region_train$Day)
xreg_region_new <- as.factor(xreg_region_new_m$Day)
mod_region <- aggregated_region_train %>% 
  model( 
    arima = ARIMA(sum ~ xreg_region)
  )


fc_region <- mod_region %>% 
  forecast(h='7 days', newdata = xreg_region_new)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, you need to create the variables before modelling. So add the factor version of `Day` before calling the model function.

Second, you need all variables in the tsibble, not as separate objects as per the comments.

The following code will work with your data.

```
library(tidyverse)
library(tsibble)
library(fable)
aggregated_region <- readRDS('aggregated_region.rds') %>%
  mutate(Day = as.factor(Day))
train <- aggregated_region %>% 
  filter(Date < '2020-02-11')
test <- aggregated_region %>% 
  filter(Date >= '2020-02-11') 

mod_region <- train %>% 
  model(arima = ARIMA(sum ~ Day)) 
fc_region <- mod_region %>% 
  forecast(new_data = test)
```